# Animation on Navigation Drawer not smooth on all devices

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-animation, navigation-drawer

I have a Navigation Drawer in my application with the following controls:

1) ImageView and ProgressBar
2) ListView below the ImageView and ProgressBar.

Every Element in this list is Animated on Drawer open, I am animating the Listview Elements as follows:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {



        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
        }


        ImageView imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);

        AnimatorSet sunSet = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(MainActivity.con, R.animator.sun_swing);
        AnimatorSet wheelSet = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(MainActivity.con, R.animator.wheel_spin);
        //set the view as target
        sunSet.setTarget(imgIcon);
        //start the animation
        sunSet.start();

        wheelSet.setTarget(imgIcon);
        //start the animation
        wheelSet.start();


        ObjectAnimator textAnim2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(txtTitle, "x",convertView.getWidth()-(txtTitle.getWidth()/2), (convertView.getWidth()/2)-70);

        textAnim2.setDuration(1000);
        textAnim2.setRepeatCount(0);
        textAnim2.start();

        txtTitle.setTypeface(tf); 
        txtTitle.setTextSize(18);

        imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());    
        txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());
        //convertView.startAnimation(getMaximAnim());

        if(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()){
            txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
        }else{
            // hide the counter view
            txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

This is my wheel_spin:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:ordering="sequentially" >

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1000"
        android:propertyName="rotation"
        android:repeatCount="0"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:valueFrom="100"
        android:valueTo="0"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

</set>
```

This is my sun_swing:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:ordering="sequentially" >

    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1000"
        android:propertyName="x"
        android:repeatCount="0"
        android:valueFrom="230"
        android:valueTo="20"
        android:valueType="floatType" />

</set>
```

In the manifest:

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme" >
```

in onDrawerOpen

```
runOnUiThread(run);
```

and my run is:

```
final Runnable run = new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                //reload content


                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mDrawerList.invalidateViews();
                mDrawerList.refreshDrawableState();

            }
        };
```

I am doing the above so that I get the animation always, when I open the nav Drawer. I find my animation is working on most of the phones, however some phones between 4.0 and 4.4 are running this animation with jitters. What can be the possible cause and how to avoid/overcome the same?

This is the trace between nav drawer open and close calls:

[image]

#### Edit 2: I have implemented much from SGal's answer below and my updated code looks as follows:

```
 public class NavDrawerListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {




    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    String fontPath = "fonts/HelveticaNeue-Light.otf";
    Typeface tf; 
    ObjectAnimator textAnim2;
    ObjectAnimator spin;
    ObjectAnimator swing;




    public NavDrawerListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems){
        this.context = context;
        this.navDrawerItems = navDrawerItems;
        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), fontPath);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return navDrawerItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {       
        return navDrawerItems.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        System.out.println("Position: "+position);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        if (convertView == null) {

            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
            viewHolder.imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
            viewHolder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            viewHolder.txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);



        }

        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        //  if(position == 0){
        textAnim2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewHolder.txtTitle, "x",convertView.getWidth()-(viewHolder.txtTitle.getWidth()/2), ((viewHolder.imgIcon.getWidth())+30));
        textAnim2.setDuration(1000);
        textAnim2.setRepeatCount(0);

        spin = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewHolder.imgIcon, "rotation", 70f , 0f);
        spin.setDuration(1000);
        spin.setRepeatCount(0);

        swing = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewHolder.imgIcon, "x",convertView.getWidth()-(viewHolder.txtTitle.getWidth()+80), 30);
        swing.setDuration(1000);
        swing.setRepeatCount(0);

        /*  }else if(position == 1){
            textAnim2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewHolder.txtTitle, "x",convertView.getWidth()-(viewHolder.txtTitle.getWidth()/2), ((viewHolder.imgIcon.getWidth())+30));
            textAnim2.setDuration(1000);
            textAnim2.setRepeatCount(0);

            spin = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewHolder.imgIcon, "rotation", 70f , 0f);
            spin.setDuration(1000);
            spin.setRepeatCount(0);

            swing = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewHolder.imgIcon, "x",convertView.getWidth()-(viewHolder.txtTitle.getWidth()+120), 30);
            swing.setDuration(1000);
            swing.setRepeatCount(0);
        }else if(position == 2){
            textAnim2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewHolder.txtTitle, "x",convertView.getWidth()-(viewHolder.txtTitle.getWidth()/2), ((viewHolder.imgIcon.getWidth())+30));
            textAnim2.setDuration(1000);
            textAnim2.setRepeatCount(0);

            spin = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewHolder.imgIcon, "rotation", 70f , 0f);
            spin.setDuration(1000);
            spin.setRepeatCount(0);

            swing = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewHolder.imgIcon, "x",convertView.getWidth()-(viewHolder.txtTitle.getWidth()+140), 30);
            swing.setDuration(1000);
            swing.setRepeatCount(0);
        } */


        swing.start();
        textAnim2.start();
        spin.start();




        viewHolder.txtTitle.setTypeface(tf); 
        viewHolder.txtTitle.setTextSize(18);

        viewHolder.imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());    
        viewHolder.txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

        if(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()){
            viewHolder.txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
        }else{
            viewHolder.txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imgIcon;
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtCount;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all findViewById is expensive, that is why it is always a great idea to use the ViewHolder pattern.

Second of all you are doing 2 xml animation inflations on every getView() call. XML inflations are even more expensive operations.

Consider rewriting your getView method like so. Moved Animator inflation to adapter constructor and reusing them in getView() also added a viewHolder to improve list scroll performance (useful if you have a long menu list):

```
private Activity ctx;
private AnimatorSet sunSet;
private AnimatorSet wheelSet;

public MyAdapter(Activity ctx){
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.sunSet = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(ctx, R.animator.sun_swing);
    this.wheelSet = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(ctx, R.animator.wheel_spin);
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = ctx.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, parent, false);

        viewHolder.imgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        viewHolder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        viewHolder.txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();

    AnimatorSet sunSetClone = sunSet.clone();
    sunSetClone.setTarget(viewHolder.imgIcon);
    sunSetClone.start();

    AnimatorSet wheelSetClone = wheelSet.clone();
    wheelSetClone.setTarget(viewHolder.imgIcon);
    wheelSetClone.start();

    ObjectAnimator textAnim2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewHolder.txtTitle, "x",convertView.getWidth()-(viewHolder.txtTitle.getWidth()/2), (convertView.getWidth()/2)-70);

    textAnim2.setDuration(1000);
    textAnim2.setRepeatCount(0);
    textAnim2.start();

    viewHolder.txtTitle.setTypeface(tf); 
    viewHolder.txtTitle.setTextSize(18);

    viewHolder.imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());    
    viewHolder.txtTitle.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getTitle());

    if(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCounterVisibility()){
        viewHolder.txtCount.setText(navDrawerItems.get(position).getCount());
    }else{
        viewHolder.txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imgIcon;
    TextView txtTitle;
    TextView txtCount;
}
```

One other performance improvement you can add is with `imageView.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon());` 
As [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29) states:

> setImageResource: This does Bitmap reading and decoding **on the UI
>   thread**, which can cause a latency hiccup. If that's a concern,
>   consider using setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) or
>   setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap) and BitmapFactory instead.

Personaly I like to use [AsyncDrawable](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html)

EDIT: Just realised that it will only animate one list item because we always override the target view. Luckily AnimatorSet implements clone() as "deep copy" with all values reset even if you clone a running animation, so I updated my code instead of:

```
    sunSet.reset();
    sunSet.setTarget(viewHolder.imgIcon);
    sunSet.start();

    wheelSet.reset();
    wheelSet.setTarget(viewHolder.imgIcon);
    wheelSet.start();
```

to be this:

```
    AnimatorSet sunSetClone = sunSet.clone();
    sunSetClone.setTarget(viewHolder.imgIcon);
    sunSetClone.start();

    AnimatorSet wheelSetClone = wheelSet.clone();
    wheelSetClone.setTarget(viewHolder.imgIcon);
    wheelSetClone.start();
```

Cloning is still ways faster than XML inflation.

Comment: Great insights, I will definitely implement the suggestions and get back to you within 24 hours :)

Comment: I just implemented your code and without reading the changes I thought clone was there from the beginning. It works flawless. However I still get a small flicker on some phones. It works super on a Nexus 5 with 5.0.1 however I am unable to achieve the same effect on a Xaiomi Redmi 1S. Thanks a ton for your help, I learnt quite a lot things from your answer  :)

Comment: I am now trying to convert the xml animations to Java code as you suggested that xml animations are pretty slow.

Comment: You are welcome, sir. Glad I could help. If you're still experiencing jank you should replace the imgIcon.setImageResource(navDrawerItems.get(position).getIcon()); with something that is not decoding bitmaps on the UI thread. That is probably the reason now. Either post it to UI from a different thread, use some sort of AsyncDrawable (see my link in the answer) or just store bitmaps in the navDrawerItems list decoded them when navDrawerItems list was constructed and just call something like imgIcon.setImageBitmap(navDrawerItems.get(position).getBitmap());

Comment: Thanks a ton @SGal. I am working on the second important point you mentioned - that is the bitmap :) Will post updates here as I clear the junk!